# Injectivity of inclusion with tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I know that tensor product does not preserves inclusion in general, but is there any concrete example of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$, say $i:I \hookrightarrow J$ such that $i \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}:I \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow J \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is not an inclusion?

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $pI=I \cap pJ$. So for instance $J=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $I=(p,x)$ is an offender.

Comment: @Aphelli Isn't $pI = (p^2, px)$ and $I \cap pJ = (p)$ ?

Comment: Exactly! Which means that the class of $p$ is nonzero at the beginning but zero at the end.

Comment: @Aphelli what's an explicit element of the kernel?? I believe $I\otimes\mathbb Z/p\to J\otimes\mathbb Z/p$ is injective.

Comment: Nevermind, $p\in I$ is in the kernel.

Comment: So $I=(p)\subset J=\mathbb Z$ would also be an example.

Comment: @Aphelli I see, I misunderstood what you meant before. Perhaps you can write this as an answer.